# InvalidOperationException Entity.SaveChanges(). Error Updating ObjectContext

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm retrieving an entity framework object from a source database, then serializing it to string, so I can transport it elsewhere. I then want to deserialize it and save it to a separate database.

The reason I'm Changing the object state, is because when the object was serialized it had already been saved to the source database (so I'm trying to fool EF into saving them to new database).

The object in question has children.

```
Using myNewDbContext = New MyEntities() ' This is using connection for new server I'm copying open too

    myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
    myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False

    myNewDbContext.Attach(myObject)
    myNewDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myObject, System.Data.EntityState.Added)

    For Each someChild In myObject.SomeChilds
        myNewDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(someChild, System.Data.EntityState.Added)
        For Each someChildChildren In someChild.MoreChildren
            myNewDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(someChildChildren, System.Data.EntityState.Added)
        Next

    Next

    myNewDbContext.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

When I call `SaveChanges()`, my object and children are saving to the other database, however an exception is throwing. I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException`

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Any ideas on how I can stop this error throwing? I can catch and ignore the error and the code works, but obviously it will be taking longer as it has to throw an exception.

Entity Framework = Version 5
VB.NET using .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a helper function, sorry for mixing and matching c# and vb.net (but our solution is mixed and most new code is c#).

```
Using myNewDbContext = New MyEntities() ' This is using connection for new server I'm copying open too

    myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
    myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False

    myNewDbContext.Attach(myObject)
    myNewDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myObject, System.Data.EntityState.Added)
    EntityFrameworkHelper.SetEntireGraphToAdded(myObject, myNewDbContext, "myObjectType")

    myNewDbContext.SaveChanges()
End Using

public static void SetEntireGraphToAdded(EntityObject entity, ObjectContext context, string name)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if ((pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing Collection {0}", pi.Name);
            var collection = (IEnumerable)pi.GetValue(entity, null);

            foreach (var val in collection)
            {
                SetEntireGraphToAdded((EntityObject)val, context, pi.Name);
            }

        }
    }

    var state = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
    state.ChangeState(EntityState.Added);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be fixed by doing much less than you do now:

```
myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
myNewDbContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = False

myNewDbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myObject, EntityState.Added)
myNewDbContext.SaveChanges()
```

When you change an entity's state from `Detached` to `Added` the *whole* object graph contained by the entity will be marked as `Added`. In your code you attach the object first and then change the state. Now only the object itself is `Added`, not the adhering object graph. That's probably why you have these loops afterwards.

I think that after these loops there are still `Detached` objects in the graph. While executing `SaveChanges`, EF will try to perform relationship fixup. This is where it encounters objects that associated with the newly saved objects, but with a foreign key value from the source database, and it reports a constraint exception.

So, `Add` the detached object and make sure that every object in its object graph must be added as well.

Comment: I still want the child entities to save to the destination db, will what you suggest work?

Comment: Sure, all child entities will be marked as `Added`.

Comment: If I do that without first attaching I get following error: The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'myProject.myObjectType'

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't paying attention! What I said works with `DbContext`, not `ObjectContext`. (and it should be `myNewDbContext.Entry(myObject).State = EntityState.Added;`) Any chance you can move to `DbContext`?

Comment: With `ObjectContext` you should use your code, but still I think that there are objects in the object graph that you don't mark as `Added`.

Comment: I found an answer (mainly based on your correct assertion that some objects are not marked as added) it is now working many thanks.